# How to acess form based on index django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to access the form based on the index value how can i do that exactly?

```
Ex:
{% for line in data_lines %}
   {{line}}
   {% with x=forloop.counter %}
   {{form.x}}
   {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Is this not working?
what error message its showing ?

Answer (score 0):

As Django discourages adding too much logic hence I don't think it's possible using built-in Django Template features. You can achieve this by sending a dict instead of data_lines and accessing via key, value as:

```
{% for key, value in data_lines.items %}
    {{value}}
    {{ form.key }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you really want it then you could write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/).